# db module "play db:import" give this exception

Tags: jdbc, playframework

I have a mysql DB that I want to import to playframework.
Using the db 1.1 module from http://www.playframework.org/modules/db-1.1/home
I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.mapping.Si
mpleValue.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/mapping/Table;)V
at org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCBinder.bindColumnToSimpleValue(JDBCBinder.java:
589)
at org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCBinder.bindPrimaryKeyToProperties(JDBCBinder.ja
va:443)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCBinder.createPersistentClasses(JDBCBinder.java:
174)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCBinder.readFromDatabase(JDBCBinder.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.readFromJDBC(JDBCMetaData
Configuration.java:40)
        at play.modules.db.Importer.main(Importer.java:88)
```

What is the problem? Is it a db configuration problem in application.conf? and if so what do I have to configure to get it right? 
thanks!

Comment: Changed the jar from hibernate 3.6.3 to hibernate 3.5.3 - and it works like a charm. or voodoo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error couple of days ago. As bArmageddon mentioned the Hibernate Version is the Problem. You can either dowgnrade Hibernate or temporarly downgrade your Play Installation.

> The 1.1 version is for the Play! 1.1
>   branch while the 1.0 is for the 1.0
>   Play! branch.